# Choosing which save file to load in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I've already managed to set up the program to save with any filename, and I'm already easily able to pick them all up in a foreach loop. How can I, from there, populate a Scroll View list in Unity *with* those save files? Like, something like this:

[image]

where every save file would take up a line in the Scroll View, one could be selected, you could hit 'load game', and it would load.

Comment: would you like to share the code that you have so for?

Comment: I don't really have any in regards to it, at this point. I was thinking of doing something like foreach (file in list_of_files), but I have no idea how to proliferate the ScrollView with buttons.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short tutorial how to do this:

[image]

**DynamicScrollView.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class DynamicScrollView : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject Prefab;
    public Transform Container;
    public List<string> files = new List<string>();

    void Start()
    {
//      files =  // LOAD FILE NAMES HERE.

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(Prefab);
            go.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = files[i];
            go.transform.SetParent(Container);
            go.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            go.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            int buttonIndex = i;
            go.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => OnButtonClick(buttonIndex));
        }
    }



    public void OnButtonClick(int index)
    {
        string file = files[index];

        Debug.Log(file);
        // Process file here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely incredible. Thank you.

Comment: I am pleased to help. Please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: I had one other question-- I saw that you deleted the Scrollbars when you created the ScrollView. How can I implement one without it screwing up the display (as I found out it apparently does when I attempted it)?

Comment: do you want to use scrollbars?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to use a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Just delete the horizontal bar. and add some right-offset to viewport from rectTranform inspector

Answer (score 0):

you could have one file with some information about all of the files... for example your main file could include
 - how many
 - name
 - some data about the save
 - creation date?

and then load that file and get all of the information from there and also just open that and add the same information when you make a new save