# unity3d get reference to list of buttons created by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created an array of 20 buttons using GUI.Button How do I get a reference to the gamebject once its created?  e.g. to change its text? There appears no way to provide a name for the button you create using the GUI.Button API.

```
    GUI.Label(new Rect(offset_x, offset_y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight), "Delta from last");
    offset_x += buttonWidth + padding_x;

    foreach (var kpi in kpis) {

        GUI.Label(new Rect(offset_x, offset_y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight), kpi);

        offset_x += buttonWidth + padding_x;
    }
```

Comment: For Unity's legacy GUI system, you don't cache references to GUI elements - you just redraw them every `OnGUI()` call. I strongly recommend using their new system if you want to use a different approach.

Comment: ah that would explain things - do you have a pointer to the new system?

Comment: Sure, here's a link to a tutorial to get you started: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui

Comment: how often is the OnGui() called? every frame?

Comment: It varies. According to the documentation, it "might be called several times per frame", which is a potential performance problem when you have to do any value recalculation.

Comment: Just don;t use `OnGUI`. In addition to Serite's answer, you can get started from here too https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: does the new UI system have an API ? I need to create the gui dynamically in code

Comment: Yes you can do it. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39615711/4366237)

Comment: @GreyCloud You can just instantiate UI elements like normal GameObjects. I'd suggest creating a prefab for each type you need (so you don't need to bother with all the extra components), then adjust their transforms/text as you instantiate them.

Comment: Thanks All, the key to this was understanding the lifecycle of OnGUI() the links to the new API in code are also very helpful