# Unity, How do i detect what OnGUI button was pressed

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, foreach

im making a dialogue system in Unity in which the player can talk to an NPC and have unique response choices for each NPC (think Elder Scrolls). I have a string array of the availible response options for the player and can also print them onto GUI buttons with a foreach loop.

What im stuck on however is figuring out how to keep track of what button was pressed.

```
void OnGUI()
{
    int i = 0;
    if(choicesReceived)
    {
        foreach (string s in playerChoices)
        {
            i++;
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(850,(50 * i) + 275, (s.Length * 4), 50), s))
            {
                Debug.Log("Chose an option");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesnt seem like a very good idea to hard code it and detect the selected button based on the string value but as of right now im having trouble comming up with something better. Thanks in advance, people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the old Unity UI system(IMGUI). Use the new UI(uGUI) which is recommended.

**1**.**GameObject**->**UI**->**Button**.

**2**.Make the new created Button a prefab then delete the original one. (Do not delete the Canvas. Simply delete the Button)

**3**.Use the `Instantiate` function to instantiate the Button.

**4**.Make the new Button to be a child of the Canvas.

**5**.Provide the button with `onClick.AddListener` function to give it a callback function. This function will be called when a `Button` is clicked.

*Creating Button/Canvas prefab example*:

[image]

*Example Script* (Code is commented):

Make sure to include `using UnityEngine.UI;`.

```
public GameObject canvas;
public GameObject buttonPrefab;
string[] playerChoices = new string[3];

void Start()
{
    playerChoices[0] = "Message 1";
    playerChoices[1] = "Message 2";
    playerChoices[2] = "Message 3";

    createButtons();
}

void createButtons()
{
    int i = 0;
    const float yPosOffset = 40f;
    float offsetCounter = 0;

    foreach (string s in playerChoices)
    {
        //Create new Button
        GameObject tempObj = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        //Rename Button
        tempObj.name = "button: " + i;
        //Make the Button child of the Canvas
        tempObj.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        Button tempButton = tempObj.GetComponent<Button>();
        //Set Button Text
        tempButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = playerChoices[i];
        //Set Button Position
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;
        pos.y = offsetCounter;
        Debug.Log(pos.y);
        tempButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = pos;
        tempButton.onClick.AddListener(() => clickAction(tempButton));

        offsetCounter += yPosOffset; //Increment Position
        i++;
    }
}

//This function will be called when a Button is clicked
void clickAction(Button buttonClicked)
{
    //Debug.Log("Clicked Button: " + buttonClicked.name);
    Debug.Log("Clicked Button: " + buttonClicked.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text);
}
```

Comment: I get an error for now but this is a fantastic setup. I can definetly work with this. Thanks you very much!

Comment: I tried to make it basic as possible. I did not get any error. As you can see in the image, the script I used worked after pressing play. That's exactly the-same with this script here. What is your error?

Comment: Its already fixed, just a simple matter of me leaving the index incrementation at the top of the loop rather than at the bottom.

Comment: I noticed `i++;` at the top of your code instead of the Button but do not use `OnGUI` for whatever reason unless you are making an Editor plugin. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using Unity's new UI system rather than using OnGui. [Starter Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui)

This is much easier to develop and has a built in event system you can use for what you are trying to do.

[image: Example of UI button and OnClick event]

In the OnClick event you can call a specific script method and pass in which button you pressed.

Documentation => [Unity UI Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html)

In addition, when approaching a dialogue system the amount of text strings you would have to write in a class can get out of hand. So you may want to take the approach of deserializing a JSON or XML file with the dialogue in it.

For example here's some JSON:

```
`{
   "id": 001,
   "dialogue":"I used to be an adventurer like you...",
   "responses":[002, 003]
 },
 {
   "id": 002,
   "dialogue":"Wait.I know you...",
   "responses":[]
 },
 {
   "id": 003,
   "dialogue":"Be careful out there.",
   "responses":[]
 }`
```

Then all the responses are kept out of your code you just need to refer to the id you need.

Comment: I know this is not the exact answer to the question you asked but the OnGui is underdeveloped and the new UI can still be fully controlled by script.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll see if i can get further with that.

Answer (score -1):

```
i
```

is the answer.

This variable holds index for the button. Starting from 1,2,3...N

try this log message:

```
Debug.Log("Chose an option : " + i);
```

**UPDATE :**

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019021/unity-how-do-i-detect-what-ongui-button-was-pressed/40019989?noredirect=1#comment67317034_40019989), you need to use uGUI as its best for your current scenario and for later use as well.

I believe this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39615711/4366237

Comment: Ive tried that, it does indeed give me the index of the button, i can also tell it to print the string on the button, however it falls appart when taking into account that the amount of response options is variable. I'd have to hard code some values which would hurt its reuseability. Thanks though

Comment: @Wopsie check the link in my answer.

Comment: yeah this is nearly the same as what Programmer showed me. This should work as well. Eitherway, it all works perfectly now, so thank you for your suggestions and examples!

Answer (score -1):

```
Button button = SomeGameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        //Put your logic here
    }
);
```